# "Expression Too Complex" error on simple property assignment

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I'm getting (fairly reguarly) an "Error 16: Expression too complex" runtime error on a simple assigment to a property from a class.

```
public property PropertyName() as double
    PropertyName = mvarPropertyName
end property
```

The debug window points to the crash being on the assignment line in the above code.
Some inital reading here and elsewhere suggested that it was related to the line calling the property. However, that now looks like this:

```
variableName = ObjectName.PropertyName
```

And all arithmetic is done with variableName.
Even more oddly, if I just hit debug, then resume/F5 immediatley, everything is fine.
Trying to use the error handling code to do this doesn't seem to have worked however.

Any ideas what is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using `Not (Not MyArray)` to test for uninitialized arrays. This uses a bug in the compiler that has a known side effect of destabilizing the run-time leading to "Expression too complex" on random places.

[VB6 - Returning/Detecting Empty Arrays](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736285-VB6-Returning-Detecting-Empty-Arrays) is fairly complete thread on different ways to test for empty and uninitialized arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A string expression is too complicated. Strings not assigned to variables (such as those returned by functions) are assigned to temporary locations during string expression evaluation. Having a large number of these strings can cause this error. Try assigning these strings to variables and use the variables in the expression instead.

Comment: In the situation described above, strings are not involved at any point. Every variable mentioned is a double.